# Where are Blue Screen of Death events logged on Windows XP and how can I view the history of them?

Tags: windows-xp, logging, bsod

I got a Blue Screen Of Death on reboot.

Where are events like this logged on Windows XP and how can I view the history of the BSODs?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/42386/pc-blue-screens-and-then-instantly-reboots-how-do-i-stop-this-or-find-the-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer

Comment: `Win+R` -> type `eventvwr` -> ENTER :)

Comment: A description of where to check for events causing the BSOD would be relevant.

Comment: Same for Windows 10.

Answer (score 14):

[BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) by Nirsoft is a much better solution than Event Viewer; Event Viewer does work, but this provides the information in a better format and much faster.

Comment: If you haven't tried BlueScreenView before check it out - I was incredibly surprised. I ran it and it pretty much told me straight out which 1 of my drivers was the problem on the first screen

Answer (score 4):

In Windows XP/2000/NT4, sort the System event log by the 'Source' heading. Look for an event source of SaveDump. In Vista/7/8 look for BugCheck. There will be a status code that you can look up, such as 0xC0000050. Change the C to a 0 before searching it on the web.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your pc set to capture minidumps, you can try [Who Crashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed), it automates looking for some of the common causes of BSODs.

Answer (score 0):

If the event log doesn't help (which it often doesn't for BSODs), and you're feeling adventurous, you can also set your system to automatically save a minidump of the crahs, and then use WinDBG to determine exactly what caused it.  See https://web.archive.org/web/20101214165843/http://elliottback.com/wp/how-to-analyze-windows-xp-bsod-minidump-files/ for an example