# How to screenshot a Blue Screen Of Death (BSOD)

Tags: windows, crash, bsod, screenshot

I am using windows 7. Recently my computer crashed, and displayed the dreaded BSOD:

[image: BSOD]

I was trying to copy down the error message, but I didn't have enough time. Is it possible to take a screenshot of the BSOD?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/166163/capturing-blue-screen-of-death-bsod-screen or http://superuser.com/questions/42386/pc-blue-screens-and-then-instantly-reboots-how-do-i-stop-this-or-find-the-error

Comment: If you disable the [automatic restart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2621246/en-us), you'll have all the time you need to note down the information and/or to take a picture using a camera.