# BSOD in win32.sys when using Google Chrome

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, bsod

Every so often I get a BSOD with an error in win32.sys when using Google Chrome. It's usually immediately after the PC boots, but not always, and only ever happens with Chrome and not any other program. It's been happening for a while with previous versions of Chrome as well as the current (Version 7.0.517.44).

Running WinDbg gives the following information:

> Probably caused by : win32k.sys ( win32k!GreGetGlyphIndicesW+af )

The full information is:

```
EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

FAULTING_IP: 
win32k!GreGetGlyphIndicesW+af
bf953c37 8b4004          mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+4]

TRAP_FRAME:  9f8d9c00 -- (.trap 0xffffffff9f8d9c00)
ErrCode = 00000000
eax=00000000 ebx=00000100 ecx=000000ba edx=e1444404 esi=e3573000 edi=e1444008
eip=bf953c37 esp=9f8d9c74 ebp=9f8d9c8c iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00010246
win32k!GreGetGlyphIndicesW+0xaf:
bf953c37 8b4004          mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+4] ds:0023:00000004=????????
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x8E

PROCESS_NAME:  chrome.exe

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from bf94b2c4 to bf953c37

STACK_TEXT:  
9f8d9c8c bf94b2c4 e16269c8 e3573200 e13e0008 win32k!GreGetGlyphIndicesW+0xaf
9f8d9d28 bf94b340 10010def 0012efe8 00000100 win32k!NtGdiGetGlyphIndicesWInternal+0xf2
9f8d9d48 8054164c 10010def 0012efe8 00000100 win32k!NtGdiGetGlyphIndicesW+0x1b
9f8d9d48 7c90e514 10010def 0012efe8 00000100 nt!KiFastCallEntry+0xfc
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0012ed58 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0x7c90e514


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
win32k!GreGetGlyphIndicesW+af
bf953c37 8b4004          mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+4]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32k!GreGetGlyphIndicesW+af

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: win32k

IMAGE_NAME:  win32k.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4c7d06ce

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x8E_win32k!GreGetGlyphIndicesW+af

BUCKET_ID:  0x8E_win32k!GreGetGlyphIndicesW+af
```

I've also been having an occasional problem where Chrome won't render some fonts correctly - it just displays a series of squares (□). Changing the font size "fixes" the problem as does restarting Chrome. Could the two be related? (I'm guessing that they are). This problem also affects Firefox and IE (it's just that Chrome is my default browser).

Is there anything further I can do to narrow down the cause of the BSOD? I don't really want to do a full reinstall of Windows if I can help it.

What I haven't done yet is run a memory test, that's next on the agenda.

This is related (tangentially) to my old question on what to do when [PC Blue Screens and then instantly reboots.](https://superuser.com/q/42386/289) as that was the same cause but as I had to rebuild (well effectively replace as it needed new m/b, CPU, memory and graphics card) the PC I didn't follow that up.

Comment: It's important to note that no application should ever be able to cause an exception in kernel mode (i.e. BSOD). Any BSOD is the fault of either a 3rd party driver, bad RAM/hard drive, or core OS components. In this case it appears there was a bug introduced to XP SP3 by a security update. But you can't blame a user-mode application for a blue-screen; unless it installs drivers (which Chrome does not).

Comment: @Ian - point taken. Perhaps I should have put "causes" (in quotes). It's the only application that manifests the problem, so the mistake is easy to make.

Comment: i didn't want to come off as though i was defending, or sticking up for Chrome. i just wanted to make the point - as it helps in diagnosing the problem. Given that Chrome can't cause a BSOD it starts pointing to the possible culprits.

Comment: @Ian - no - we need to be accurate in our terminology and descriptions otherwise we're not helping people find the right information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the WinDbg "probable cause" is GreGetGlyphIndices and Glyphs are character shapes used in Fonts, then yes, it is likely related to your font problems in Chrome.

Perhaps a specific Font, one used by Chrome, is triggering this problem?

I would change the fonts [used by Chrome](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95416) (so far as is possible) and see if the problem recurs.

Comment: I don't think it's a font specific to Chrome as I do get the rendering problem in other browsers (it's just that Chrome is my default browser). The fonts the page is looking for are "Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"

Comment: What Firefox does (and I guess Chrome too) is, if it is trying to display a character and can't find a glyph for that character in the configured font, it looks for that glyph in other fonts on your system. I would suspect you have an installed font that is broken in some way that triggers a bug in Win32.sys.

Comment: If your search this [Chrome source](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/WebKit/WebCore/platform/graphics/chromium/GlyphPageTreeNodeChromiumWin.cpp?view=markup&pathrev=8483) for GetGlyphIndices you can see it seems to be relevant (but not helpful).

Answer (score 4):

OK big boys... See post #9 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=10011#c9 for the fix which involves installing a MS hotfix on top of XP SP3.

Be careful to use the full link to the hotfix http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ec4b7d80-79b6-4035-92a3-3992a9e09718&displaylang=en

Comment: Interesting. I didn't come across this when I searched for `GreGetGlyphIndicesW` back in November of last year. I'll give this hot fix a go - but as I'm upgrading to Windows 7 in the next couple of weeks and the problem seems to have "gone away" at the moment it'll be hard to tell if it's worked. It's a shame the hot fix page doesn't give more details on the problem.