# System failure - need diagnostic recommendation

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, ssd, bios

I have big problem with my computer. Configuration is:

- Intel i7 + 6x2GB OCZ DDR3
- Motheboard: Asus P6T Deluxe V2, HDD controller configured to AHCI
- Main drive: OCZ Vertex 2 (SSD) - contains all installed programs and system
- Second drive: Samsung SpinPoint - contains User profiles, ProgramData, virtual machines and databases
- Third drive: Samsung SpinPoint - data drive + backups
- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

I have never had any problem with this computer until now. During weekend my computer completely crashed without any reason. Each time I tried to boot to Windows I got BSOD with message BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO and automatic restart (I didn't install any new SW or HW). But after restart main OCZ drive was disconnected (not detected by BIOS). When I turned off and on computer, the drive was again connected. It also happend every single time I tried to repair installation somehow. It ended with some error and after restart drive was disconnected. The only thing which worked was format + fresh install.

After installing almost everything I wanted to install Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (complete installation without SQL Server Express). During installation of VS itself I always get BSOD - it is too fast so I'm not able to read description. After restart it searches for all disk drives for really long time and sometimes it changes boot drive so the system is not able to start - Bootmgr not found. After reconfiguring BIOS the system starts. There is no event describing the failure in Event viewer. Installing VS 2010 is absolutely necessary for me.

I need help with diagnostic. I need to find where is the problem - I expect that the problem is in OCZ drive or in HDD controller on motherboard but I don't know how to find it. All components still have valid warranty. Can you recommend me some approach or tools to find the problem?

**Edit:**

I'm still looking for source of the problem. New information is that Windows are not able to perform check disk (Chkdsk) on the SSD system drive. After restarting it always starts checking drive and in part where files are checked it fails with BSOD - BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO. After next restart and skipping check disk tests the system runs.

Comment: I would say your HDD is failing, you will likely need to replace it.

Comment: @Jeff: Ok but I would like to be sure that the HDD is responsible for that.

Comment: Have you stress tested your memory?...http://www.memtest.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Cause:**
>
> The BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO bug check occurs if the SYSTEM hive is corrupt. However, this corruption is unlikely, because the boot loader, known as NT Loader (NTLDR) in versions of Windows prior to Vista, checks a hive for corruption when it loads the hive.
>
> This bug check can also occur if some critical registry keys and values are missing. Thee keys and values might be missing if a user manually edited the registry.
>
> **Resolution:**
>
> Try restarting the computer by selecting "last known good configuration" in the boot options.
>
> If the restart does not fix the problem, the registry damage is too extensive. You must reinstall the OS or use the Emergency Repair Disk (ERD) that you previously created by using the Windows Backup tool.
>
> — [Bug Check 0x74: BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO: Cause & Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559188(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I know about this description but it doesn't look like my problem. When this happend first time last week I was unable to do anything except formatting the disk. If this happens during chkdsk I do not need to select last known good config. It simply starts if I avoid check disk.

Comment: As you have this on two installations and software resolution fails, it's most likely to be an hardware issue. So there isn't anything more than trying to see whether it's the SSD, the SATA cable or the Motherboard that has a bad connection. Try swapping your SSD to another SATA port, do a reinstall and see if it solves the problem. If it does then your SATA port/cable is broken; if not, it's more likely a bigger problem with your SSD, not your motherboard as other disks run fine. Memory problems like Moab mentioned are very unlikely given that the error is the exact same... Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I happened upon this question when looking for recovery methods for an OCZ Agility 2 SSD.

Apparently the failure rate of this drives hovers around 5%, so in all likelihood the drive itself is causing your troubles.

While your troubles aren't as catastrophic as mine, I do believe it is an indication the drive is on its way to complete failure, if it hasn't failed completely by now, obviously.