# Cloning Win7 installation from HDD to HDD

Tags: windows-7, installation

I remember ten years ago cloning Win installation by copying all the files from HDD to another  HDD using a bootable CD software. Then in the recovery console doing fdisk / mbr, to fix the master boot record so that the new HD can boot the old system.

My question is this still the normal way to do it with Win7? Also what are the available utilities today that I can use on the bootable CD?

Comment: You want to do an exact copy, like a deployment? There is imagex which will create an image. There is sysprep if you need it. There is Ghost, Clonezilla, Acronis which will do a direct clone. Depends what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You could even use dd to do it if you're good with a command line.

Comment: Possible dupe of: [What utility can move my Windows boot partition over to another hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive?lq=1), or [Is it possible to clone system drive in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/242322/is-it-possible-to-clone-system-drive-in-windows-7?rq=1), or [How do you clone a Windows 7 installation?](http://superuser.com/questions/123372/how-do-you-clone-a-windows-7-installation)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*The initially accepted answer did not work for me and so I have to post an answer myself.*

After trying(and failing) few tools, I have ended up downloading [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)

- Burn the image
- Restart PC into BIOS and verify that the boot device order is set to [first boot device]  - CD-ROM
- Restart the PC and it should boot into the Ultimate Boot CD
- Chose [HDD]
- Chose [Hard Disk Cloning]
- Chose [CopyWipe]
- Set the source HDD and the target HDD with an [expand] option (Use F6 to view the partitions)
- Start the copy process.
- After the files were copied to the new HDD, shutdown and disconnect the old HDD
- Replace the Ultimate Boot CD with the Win 7 instalation CD and boot up into Win 7 installation
- Chose [repair installation]([image])
- Click OK when prompted and restart.

Answer (score 4):

To clone a partition, you can use any partitioning software that you want (Gparted, Acronis, Windows (though that will mean you cannot copy the active partition)).

For the bootloader part, install a windows installer disk, and run the following commands:

1. `bootrec /rebuildbcd`
2. `bootsect /nt60 D: /force /mbr`
3. Make sure the partition is set as active

   1. `diskpart`
   2. `select <disk number>`
   3. `select <partition number>`
   4. active

Comment: Any particular product from Acronis?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Comment: Disk director I think. To be honest though, that recently caused me problems, so I would recommend using Gparted

Comment: Any idea about a software that supports RAID10? Gparted did not fulfill the expectations.

Comment: I did exactly this using gParted and this tutorial on HowToGeek: http://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/GParted  It worked just fine.  I cloned my HDD from a 250GB \@5400 HDD to a WD Black 750GB \@7200.  After I moved the partitions to the new drive, I had to use the Windows Installation disk to perform a boot repair - and I had to run it twice; it did something each time, but not all at once, I suppose.  But it worked - took me about two hours to read the tutorial and everything.  It helps to have an external USB HDD dock, though!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can still do it. You can use Imgburn to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do this, I would plug the new hard drive into the old system with an external enclosure, then boot the system from an Ubuntu Live USB or CD (as much as I hate Ubuntu, it's the easiest option available) and run `dd` to clone the old drive to the new drive (assuming that the new drive is larger than or equal in capacity to the old drive).

This eliminates the need to fix the MBR.

After cloning the drive, if the new drive is larger than the old drive, I would use GPartEd (included with Ubuntu as last I checked) to expand the cloned partition to fill the drive.

[Further information on drive cloning with `dd`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19141/clone-a-hard-drive-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/)
[Ubuntu Live USB information](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
[Ubuntu Live CD information](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

With Windows 7 you do not need any separate software; it has disk imaging tools built in. This is a good tutorial on how to create and restore images of your hard drives: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4241/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-7/

Comment: Good luck with that one