# Mirroring (cloning?) local and network partitions to an external HDD

Tags: windows-xp

This being a new area to me, I'm not even sure on the terminology. Cloning, I believe is the correct term for what I'm trying to do.

I have a machine which has several local and several network drives (all show up in Windows Explorer with their designated letters for separate partitions). I would like to clone them all (everything, including an OS) to an external USB HDD, so I can make copy everything to an identical machine with minimum of fuss.

How would one go about that?

I'm guessing booting from the external HDD and ... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to clone system drive in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/242322/is-it-possible-to-clone-system-drive-in-windows-7)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/123372/how-do-you-clone-a-windows-7-installation

Comment: From what I can tell Driveimage works from Win, while I'm looking to clone the drive entirely including the OS. Understand that for cloning network drives one will have to boot from the system HDD, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few software options for making clones (bit-to-bit copies) of partitions, including free options like EaseUS, Paragon, Acronis, etc. However, I am not sure that they can do bit-to-bit clones of network drives. For those, you might have to do manual copies.

The paid versions could have those features. A quick search suggests that Acronis supports network drives.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Use [**dd**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) utility. Primitive, powerful, reliable, free. Available on all linux distributions and also available as [**dd for windows**](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd)

Definitely worth a try.