# How to turn off automatic restart when BSOD happens?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PC Blue Screens and then instantly reboots. How do I stop this or find the error later?](https://superuser.com/questions/42386/pc-blue-screens-and-then-instantly-reboots-how-do-i-stop-this-or-find-the-error)

Is it possible to turn off or stop automatic restart when BSOD happens? It is so quick that I'm not able to read the description.