# How to avoid reboot when blue screen in vmware?

Tags: windows-xp, vmware

The guest OS is windows XP,and when blue screen happens,it reboots at once.

How to make it stop there so I can check the details about blue screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PC Blue Screens and then instantly reboots. How do I stop this or find the error later?](http://superuser.com/questions/42386/pc-blue-screens-and-then-instantly-reboots-how-do-i-stop-this-or-find-the-error)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you meant a BSOD, that can be configured in the VM (WinXP) itself.

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Open *System*
3. Go to the *Advanced* tab
4. Press the *Settings* button at the *Startup and recovery* section
5. At the *System failure* section, tick the *Automatically restart* box
6. Press *OK* to save the changes