# Randomly bluescreens on my computer

Tags: windows-7, desktop-computer

Currently I am experiencing randomly computer crashes. I just installed Windows 7 and I got a new SSD.

The event log says:

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This
>   error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or
>   lost power unexpectedly.

Something about `Kernel-Power`

I am not sure how to get to the ground of the problem. Has anyone an idea?

[image: Here a screenshot]

Comment: It would help a lot if you post the actual stop error code. If the computer restarts before you get it, [this question](http://superuser.com/a/42388/97028) can help you.

Comment: @HotPizzaBox - Have you updated the firmware on the SSD?  The full BSOD log file is helpful or at the very least the error code.

Comment: Okay, I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Check this KB Article from Microsoft and follow all steps:

**Windows Kernel event ID 41 error "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first" in Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, or Windows Server 2008 R2**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504