# blue screen of death at shutdown windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bsod

this is a problem because though it will restart just fine, nothing will install... it happens every time I restart the computer.

here are the details.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   7f
  BCP1: 0000000000000008
  BCP2: 0000000080050031
  BCP3: 00000000000006F8
  BCP4: FFFFF80002AC6327
  OS Version:   6_1_7600
  Service Pack: 0_0
  Product:  256_1
```

Comment: any drivers installed lately for hardware? changes? Anything in the events? Is there any new hardware installed/attached?

Comment: BroadWave Streaming Audio Server - I uninstalled it. I don't remember having any problems when it was installed. That is all I can recall.

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/96879-blue-screen-death-bsod-posting-instructions.html might help u

Comment: Boot your computer in safe mode and then shutdown and check if the problem persists..

Comment: [PC Blue Screens and then instantly reboots. How do I stop this or find the error later?](http://superuser.com/q/42386)

Comment: you get a **Bug Check 0x7F: UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE** We need the file **C:\Windows\Memory.dmp** to look at it with Windbg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like processor problem : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842465

> This problem occurs if one or more of the processors in the computer:
>
> - Require a microcode update that is not applied by the computer's basic
>   input/output system (BIOS).
> - Are damaged or defective.
> - Are operating
>   outside their specified ranges for temperature, power, or other
>   conditions.